# laravelcollective multiple selection json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: laravel

I have just started Laravel. In one of the forms, I have a multiple selection that I have written as follows:

```
<select name="OtherOffices[]" id="OtherOffices[]" style="width:180px;"
        class="myform-select" multiple>
        <option value="" selected>Select Offices</option>
               @foreach ($offices as $office)
                     <option value="{{ $office->id }}">
                             {{ $office->caption }}
                      </option>
               @endforeach
</select>
```

At the time of creating the table, I have also defined the field type as json:

```
 $table->json('OtherOffices')->nullable();
```

When saving data, the data is saved as json:

[image]

But when calling to edit the data, the values stored in the table are not displayed on the select object as they are selected.
While the rest of the objects on the screen display their respective values correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show selected values from database which are stored in json form, you first have to decode the value in array and pass into blade file and then you can pass in select tag.

In Controller:

```
$selectedOffices = json_decode($user->selected_offices); // Decode JSON to array
return view('blade', compact('selectedOffices', 'offices'));
```

then in Select tag in blade file:

```
<select name="OtherOffices[]" id="OtherOffices[]" style="width:180px;" class="myform-select" multiple>
    <option value="" disabled>Select Offices</option>
    @foreach ($offices as $office)
        <option value="{{ $office->id }}" 
            {{ in_array($office->id, $selectedOffices) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            {{ $office->caption }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: i added $selectedOffices =json_decode($task->OtherOffices); but recive error:
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: if it is already in array format then you don't need to decode it. try implementing select tag code with
`$selectedOffices = $task->OtherOffices; //add this in controller `